# What is the equivalent in Swift to NSParameterAssert?

Tags: ios, swift

If there is no equivalent what is the suggested way to check for nil params.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no need for it. If your function doesn't accept nil parameters, make sure the parameters aren't optionals.

If you want to assert that a value is non-nil you can use a regular assert.

```
assert(value != nil, "nil value")
```